# Why different different contexts in one view?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a cart controller. User can add item to his wish list. If we have not any wish list we should create default one. This is works 2-3 times, if i add, then delete, then add again. And then i get error:

> Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'wishList' between objects
>   in different contexts

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
        var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!
        var shopItems:[ShopItem] = []
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        override func viewDidLoad() {
             self.fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                    managedObjectContext: self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            self.fetchResultController.delegate = self
            do {
                try fetchResultController.performFetch()
                self.shopItems = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [ShopItem]
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }

        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

            let addToWishListAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Add to wish list", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
                var wishListResults:[WishList] = []
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WishList")
                var wishList:WishList
                fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

                //...some other code

                wishList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WishList", inManagedObjectContext: self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! WishList
                wishList.setValue("Default wish list", forKey: "title")
                wishList.setValue("My wish list", forKey: "desc")

                let shopItem = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ShopItem

                shopItem.setValue(true, forKey: "inWishList")
                shopItem.setValue(wishList, forKey: "WishList")

                do {
                    try self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Why context changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to create and save CoreData objects on a different thread than which the managed object context was created.  The handler for the UITableViewRowAction provides a block callback which will happen asynchronously on a different thread.

In order to create and save objects on a different thread you need to create another `NSManagedObjectContext` of `concurrencyType` `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and then use that from the background thread.

So here's how I would re-write your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method (because everyone wants to copy and paste, right?):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMOC.parentContext = self.appDelegate.managedContext
    let addToWishListAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Add to wish list", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        var wishListResults:[WishList] = []
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WishList")
        var wishList:WishList
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

        //...some other code

        wishList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WishList", inManagedObjectContext: privateMOC) as! WishList
        wishList.setValue("Default wish list", forKey: "title")
        wishList.setValue("My wish list", forKey: "desc")

        let shopItem = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ShopItem

        shopItem.setValue(true, forKey: "inWishList")
        shopItem.setValue(wishList, forKey: "WishList")

        do {
            try privateMOC.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Also, ensure that you are creating the `ManagedObjectContext` to use a `MainQueueConcurrencyType` as:

```
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

Comment: > Also, ensure that you are creating the ManagedObjectContext to use a MainQueueConcurrencyType as:
you mean replace this:
```let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate```  ?? Because i use this in every controller? is this normal ?

Comment: now i get error ```Illegal attempt to establish a relationship``` every time. It is not helped

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address a thread issue, and the real problem is that you are mixing objects across 2 contexts